# How are truffle artifacts different from ABI?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, dapps

How are truffle artifacts different from ABI? Do Truffle artifacts include fields that are different from ABI that is generated using remix?

Answer (score 7):

A Truffle artifact is a JSON bundle that contains a lot of useful information related to a contract like the ABI, the contract bytecode, the deployment details, compiler version, etc...

Examples:

```
{
  "contractName": "Migrations",
  "abi": [],
  "bytecode": "0x...",
  "sourceMap": "",
  "deployedSourceMap": "",
  "sourcePath": "/project/contracts/Migrations.sol",
  "ast": {},
  "legacyAST": {},
  "compiler": {
    "name": "solc",
    "version": "0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang"
  },
  "networks": {
    "17": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x42a8d8ba55faAA734Ee07eD3179047169be5419e",
      "transactionHash": "0x4e5fc578b9ea44401047fc010dd1ee20cd899b8091fe4304ce0f955dc1d4db5b"
    }
  },
  "schemaVersion": "3.0.0",
  "updatedAt": "2018-12-19T17:59:54.615Z",
  "devdoc": {},
  "userdoc": {}
}
```

The ABI generated by Remix and the ABI generated by Truffle (field `abi`) should be the exact same.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Greg's answer, this documentation provides background on what Truffle artifact's are: https://trufflesuite.github.io/artifact-updates/background.html#what-are-artifacts